# MS Access Object Required Error on Combo Box Column

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a combo box in Access named StateID. It's rowsource contains two columns one  is `ID` which is in Column 0 and another is `description` which is Column 1.

I want to populate the value of the ID column by doing something like:

```
StateID.Column(0) = rs("ID")
```

I made sure that the combobox is name `StateID`. The `rs("ID")` is also returning a value but my code breaks on the line above and I get

> Object Required

error.
I alos tried `Me.StateID.Column(0)` and `StateID.Column(0).value` but I still get the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I just tried various things and doing it this way works:

```
  With StateID
     .ColumnCount = 2
     .Value = rs("ID")
 End With
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do "something like" that because the "Column" property is Read-Only, per Microsoft Access documentation; seems like this is your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I dont' know why you don't assign the record source in design mode. Any way, in the Form Load event you can do this

```
    StateID.RowSource = "SELECT codage,nomage FROM TheTable"
```

Comment: the "RowSource" assignment does not have to be done during Load: just Requery the form or the control after the assignment is done.

Comment: I already assigned the rowsource in the design view. I am importing something from another database so I need to populate the ID field using vba. Users can still select the Ids and Description from the drop box manually